# How to prevent adding of duplicate list items in sharepoint list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api, object-model

I need to add items to a sharepoint list through object model. Before doing this i want to check whether the current item is already exist in the list or not. how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

Firstly, sharepoint allows you by default to add List items with exactly the same data.

Your best bet in this scenario, is to identify your column in the Listitem which is your Unique identifier (Usually Title). Then, in the list settings, click on the column name and select 'Yes' for Enforce Unique values.

Alternatively, as you are adding items using the Object Model, Iterate through existing items and see if a ListItem with that value exists.

Send some code example and I can help you out.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Fox's answer , there's (Obviously) the Event Receiver

You can add an event receiver on that list on Item Adding , read the item date and compare it with previous items , if match cancel adding and show message

```
public virtual void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   // Your logic here....

   properties.Cancel = true; 
   properties.ErrorMessage = "A custom error message.";
}
```